# Oldest Source for Simchas Torah Hakafos

Tags: sources-mekorot, simchat-torah, dance

What is the oldest source for hakafos on Simchas Torah? (Bonus: Why do we do hakafos on Simchas Torah?)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95828/170

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=729) site, the Machzor Vitry (12th century) was the earliest source to mention hakafos -albeit in the morning, and the Maharam M'Rutenberg (13th century) was the first to record hakafos being done at night.